# Is it possible to change the position of ActionBarDrawerToggle from left to right corner

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a right hand side Navigation Drawer so I should change the position of  ActionBarDrawerToggle from left corner to right corner for having a consistent look and feel. After hours searching it seems impossible having that. Does anyone know its solution or an alternative way to stimulate something like that?

Comment: "for having a consistent look and feel" thats exactly the opposite of what this would achieve.

Comment: Isn't it awkward having a right side navigation drawer then users have to lift up their finger and push a button on the other side of screen???

Comment: Sounds like your app is badly designed from the start. Take a look at https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: You probably CAN do this (with enough effort), but you shouldn't.

Comment: @Booger Even if I'm going to design for a rtl language?

Comment: Yes, even if you are creating for a RTL language (this is a pattern in Android, and users expect that to be in top left - and the standards specify putting it there).